# Activate UIElement on textbox from code behind

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, uielement

I have a custom WPF keyboard that I use for input in my application

```
xmlns:WpfKb="clr-namespace:WpfKb.Controls;assembly=WpfKb"
```

And in the resourcedictionary

```
<WpfKb:OnScreenKeypad x:Key="OnScreenKeypad"/>
```

In my XAML-code I use the following code to activate:

```
                    <TextBox Name="Sensor1Yoffset" Width="100" Margin="5,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource PmEditTextBox}" Text="{Binding Path=SensorOffsetY1}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                WpfKb:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard.KeyboardType="{StaticResource OnScreenKeypad}" 
                            WpfKb:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard.OpenOnFocus="False" 
                            WpfKb:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard.OpenOnMouseClick="{Binding Path=UseOnScreenKeyboard}" 
                            WpfKb:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard.Placement="Left" 
                            WpfKb:FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TheGui}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
```

Now I need to add this in the code behind, but don't know where ro start looking.

```
      TextBox ChannelName = new TextBox();
      ChannelName.Style = (MyView.TryFindResource("PmEditTextBox") as Style);
      ChannelName.Width = 300;
```

The FloatingTouchScreenKeyboardclass is defined as

```
public partial class FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AreAnimationsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AreAnimationsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAllowedToFadeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsAllowedToFade", typeof(bool), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDraggingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsDragging", typeof(bool), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragHelperAllowedToHideProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsDragHelperAllowedToHide", typeof(bool), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsKeyboardShownProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsKeyboardShown", typeof(bool), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumKeyboardOpacityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaximumKeyboardOpacity", typeof(double), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.9d));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumKeyboardOpacityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinimumKeyboardOpacity", typeof(double), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.2d));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyboardHideDelayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeyboardHideDelay", typeof(double), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(5d));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyboardHideAnimationDurationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeyboardHideAnimationDuration", typeof(double), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.5d));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyboardShowAnimationDurationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KeyboardShowAnimationDuration", typeof(double), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.5d));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DeadZoneProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DeadZone", typeof(double), typeof(FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard), new UIPropertyMetadata(5d));
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the attached properties you are setting are actually exposed by the floating keyboard's base class, `Popup`.  The `Popup` class has setter methods you can use to set the properties from C# code, e.g.:

```
Popup.SetPlacementTarget(ChannelName, TheGui)
```

For the properties with bindings, use the target's `SetBinding` method:

```
ChannelName.SetBinding(
    Popup.OpenOnMouseClickProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath("UseOnScreenKeyboard")
    });
```

Looking at the WpfKb project, I do not see any definition for the `KeyboardType` property.  Perhaps it existed in an earlier version, or maybe you are using a customized/forked version?

Comment: Excellent. Worked (almost) perfect. I needed to replace Popup with FloatingTouchScreenKeyboard

Comment: For which property?  Most of them were inherited from `Popup`.

Comment: For both of them actually. I may be missing a reference or something?
The KeyboardType property is defined further down in the code.